# Samsung galaxy S3 screenshot doesn't work

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.1-jelly-bean, screenshots

Yesterday I bought a brand new  samsung  galaxy s3. WHen I hold home button and lock button, it doesnt shot the screen. how to fix it?

Comment: at the same time?

Comment: yes... i know to use it , i had galaxy pocket before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved. it would meant to be "Home" +  "Back" + "Power".

Answer (score 2):

1. Hold <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> button and <kbd>Lock</kbd> button!
   You can't take screenshots like on Android 2+.
2. Using hand motion feature - For this enable Palm Swipe to Capture feature and swipe your hands above the phone to take a screenshot
3. Using swipe option

For reference look at the guide on [How to take screenshot on Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini](http://howtotakescreenshot.net/samsung-galaxy-s3-mini/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your palm on the side of the screen and cross it to the other side.

Comment: I know this way but I want to use `Home button` + `power button` screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stovk ROM then you can try this.

From HOME
 1. Click the MENU button and select SETTINGS.
 2. Select MOTION.
 3. Under “Hand Motion” settings, check “Palm swipe to Capture” checkbox.

just swipe your palm horizontally(L-->R/R-->L) over your screen it will capture a screen shot.

**OR**

HOLD down the <kbd>POWER</kbd> button and the <kbd>HOME</kbd> button at the same time. (Remember timing is imporatant)